# httpOnly cookie

Tags: jboss, security, httponly

I had done web scan for an application(built in struts and hibernate framework) deployed in jboss 5 which reported "`Set-cookie does not use HTTPOnly keyword. The web application does not utilize HTTPOnly cookies`". What does it mean. I looked for some post and just added one line in my j`boss/deploy/jbossweb.sar/context.xml` as

```
<SessionCookie secure="true" useHttpOnly="true" >
```

After setting that, I am getting error while running the application.
 Is there any configuration that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean

The `HttpOnly` flag in a http response header indicates to the browser that client-side access to the `JSESSION_ID` or other session-cookie type identifier should not be permitted. What this is intended to prevent is a malicious access to the session token via client side scripts  in an [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)(or other attack involving session hijacking from the client side). Currently almost all major browsers support this flag(see [this list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly#Browsers_Supporting_HTTPOnly) for supporting browsers), but it's simply ignored in browsers that don't support it. See more info on this at the [OWASP site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly)

Setting it up is similar for tomcat and forks of it, including Jboss, by including the following in your context file:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

or

```
 <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

Comment: other than configuring this in my jboss, is there any configuration required in the application?

Comment: @bablu, required? no. But you could configure a servlet filter to insert this header in every http response from your application, as a failsafe, not as a matter of necessity

Comment: In the servlet filter code, I had to add String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly"); else request.getSession(false) always returns null. I dont know why but after adding those couple of lines, the application is running successfully. So my doubt is - those 2 lines r definately required. This 2 lines i got from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly site. Here it is mentioned, for servlet version < 3 (2.4 in my case), these 2 lines are necessary

Comment: @bablu, sorry, I somehow assumed you were on a JEE platform. You're correct, for earlier (J2EE) containers, you're required to rewrite the header programmatically. The native support for httponly was introduced in servlet 3.0. Updating my answer accordingly

Comment: Wach out! First of all there are ways to get around it (i.e. java applet with debugged http connection ;) ). Secondly if you apply that in filter to every request "/*" your applets could not work because of set-cookie header in response while classloading.

Comment: @kolossus <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" /> works in jboss 5 but not in jboss 3.2.6 server. Why is it so

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```

Comment: In the log we could find the error about parsing xml.
It's a simple missing close tag issue